# ActiveRecord - Bi-directional :dependent => :destroy on has_many <-> belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

In a rails 4 application with a `has_many` `belongs_to` association, how should bi-directional `:dependent => :destroy` functionality be implemented?

Using `Contact` and `Organisation` as an example. The desired behaviour is as follows:

1. Destroying an organisation destroys the organisation and all of the associated contacts.
2. Destroying a contact associated to an organisation with multiple contacts destroys only the contact.
3. Destroying the last contact associated to an organisation destroys the contact and the associated organisation.

Setting `:dependent => :destroy` on the `has_many` satisfies conditions 1 and 2, but not 3.

```ruby
class Organisation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organisation
end
```

Setting `:dependent => :destroy` on the `belongs_to` satisfies conditions 1 and 3, but not 2.

```ruby
class Organisation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organisation, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

What's the cleanest way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: I had the same question some time ago, and used this gem https://github.com/igor04/acts_has_many#examples (instead of manual implementation for each relation) but it was with ActiveRecord3, but with new AR4 it doesn't clean unnecessary relations properly

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that achieves the desired behaviour without setting  `:dependent => :destroy`:

```
class Organisation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts

  def destroy
    self.contacts.delete_all if self.contacts.any?
    super
  end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organisation

  after_destroy :cascade_destroy

  private

  def cascade_destroy
    self.organisation.destroy if self.organisation.contacts.empty?
  end
end
```

Rather than overriding the `Organisation#destroy` I had tried setting `:dependent => :destroy` on the `has_many :contacts` association, however I believe this created an infinite loop, as it caused the app to throw a 'stack level too deep' error.

Calling `self.contacts.delete_all` seems to avoid that issue, although I don't know why.

Comment: This solution doesn't feel particularly clean. So I'll hold off on marking this answer as correct for the time being, in the hope that someone comes up with a more elegant approach.